# T-SQL find an eight character string which contains no spaces and at least 1 number from within a string and exclude it

Tags: sql, string, t-sql, parsing, design-patterns

The problem is we have many different error messages being produced and stored in a sql table
within the error message there could be an occurance of a project number 8 characters long
which would contain at least 1 number is alphanumeric and no spaces. per error message the project number may not be the same.

e.g.

```
'error found processing project: abcd12sf no funding is set'
'error found processing project: qd451srf no funding is set'
'error project 2344ddrf has no approver'
```

We want to be able to count the occurances of particular errors and so we need to strip the project number from the output

thus

```
'error found processing project: no funding is set' , 2 occurances
'error project has no approver' , 1 occurance
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: I suggest using a consistent style for error messages. As it is, there is no way to identify which part of the error message is the error code (unless you can **guarantee** that the only 8-character strings that include numeric characters will always be error codes) and therefore the problem as stated can not be solved.

Comment: If life was only so simple... but for this exercise we are ok to say we can guarantee that the only 8-character strings that include numeric codes will always be 'Project numbers' that we need to remove

Comment: can there be more than 1 project in each row ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by creating a Function that returns the project number.  I did this by finding the first integer and then position of the space after it, then counting back 8 characters you have the start and end position.

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetProjectNumber(@FullErrorMessage varchar(100))

RETURNS CHAR(8)

AS 

BEGIN

    DECLARE @ProjectNumber CHAR(8)

    SET @ProjectNumber = (
                                    SELECT  
                                    SUBSTRING(@FullErrorMessage, CHARINDEX(' ',@FullErrorMessage,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',@FullErrorMessage))-8,8)
                                )

    RETURN @ProjectNumber
END
```

Alter your table to have a computed column called ProjectNumber here is the create I did for testing but you should get the idea.

```
CREATE TABLE T_Errors(
ID int IDENTITY(1,1),
ErrorMessage varchar(1024),
ProjectNumber AS (dbo.GetProjectNumber(ErrorMessage))
CONSTRAINT PK_T_Errors PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED(ID))
```

Now you have the project number in a separate column it is easy to play with.

```
SELECT 
CleanErrorMessage = REPLACE(ErrorMessage,ProjectNumber,''),
COUNT(*) As ErrorCount
FROM T_Errors
GROUP BY REPLACE(ErrorMessage,ProjectNumber,'')
```

Comment: perfect - thanks -SELECT                                       SUBSTRING(@FullErrorMessage, CHARINDEX(' ',@FullErrorMessage,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',@FullErrorMessage))-8,8)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of valid project numbers you can do something like this.

Sample tables and data:

```
declare @Project table
(
  ProjectNumber char(8)
)

insert into @Project values
('abcd12sf'),
('qd451srf'),
('2344ddrf')

declare @Error table
(
  Error varchar(100)
)

insert into @Error values
('error found processing project: abcd12sf no funding is set'),
('error found processing project: qd451srf no funding is set'),
('error project 2344ddrf has no approver')
```

The query:

```
select P.Error,
       count(*) as ErrorCount
from @Error as E
  cross apply
    (
      select replace(E.Error, P.ProjectNumber, '') as Error
      from @Project as P
      where E.Error like '%'+P.ProjectNumber+'%'
    ) as P
group by P.Error
```

Result:

```
Error                                               ErrorCount
--------------------------------------------------  ----------
error found processing project:  no funding is set  2
error project  has no approver                      1
```

Comment: unfortunately we don't have the list of know project numbers - we are thinking of searching the string for a number - then find the next space character pos - find the previous space character pos - if the difference is 8 we have found the project and manipulate accordingly. i guess that works?

Comment: I have a better way hang on a few mins.